# Hide google Toolbar by javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, google-toolbar

Is there a way to hide the google toolbar in my browser programmable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't said which browser you are using so I'm going to assume Internet Explorer* and answer No.

If JavaScript on a web page could manipulate the browser, it would be a serious security hole and could create a lot of confusion for users.

So no... for a good reason: Security.

*. If you were using Firefox, and were talking about JavaScript within an extension to manipulate and theme the window chrome then this would be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I really think that it is imposible to do that with javascript. This is because javascript is designed to control the behaviour of the site. And the browser is not part of the site.

Of course maby you are talking about some other Google toolbar then the plugin in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot access these parts of the browser due to security issues. But you can load new browser windows without toolbars as such. I don't know exactly how (hopefully other users will help yout out), but maybe start here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web/Web_Languages/JavaScript/Q_20782379.html

(PS: I know, it's experts-exchange, but I'm not going to copy someone elses work, even if it's posted on EE).